# How to paginate in angular to display that i have reached the end of the blog?

Tags: c#, jquery, angularjs, sql-server, web-services

If I click on loadnextPosts and the pageno exceeds the pagesize, it shouldn't load any posts or it should alert that I have reached the last page. I do not know the logic for it to work. When I click on loadnextposts, it just keeps on incrementing the pagesize and when the number of posts is exceeded it keeps on incrementing. I want it to alert me that I have reached the end of the posts.

Thank you

```
.controller('blogController', function ($http, user, $scope, getAllTurtles, $route) {


                        var vm = this;

                        var pageno = 1;
                        var pagesize = 9;
                        getData(pageno, pagesize);


                        function getData(pageno, pagesize) {
                            $http({
                                url: "../Services/svBlogPost.asmx/GetAllBlogPost2",
                                method: "get",
                                params: { pn: pageno, ps: pagesize }
                            }).then(function (response) {
                                $scope.ab = response.data;
                            })
                        };


                        vm.loadNextPosts = function () {
                            pageno += 1;
                            getData(pageno, pagesize);
                            //pageno += 1;
                            //if (pageno >= pagesize) {
                            //    //pageno += 1;
                            //    getData(pageno, pagesize);
                            //}
                            //else {
                            //    alert('reached the last page');
                            //    //$("#loadNextPosts").prop('');
                            //}
                        }
                    })
```

```
                    function getData(pageno, pagesize) {
                        $http({
                            url: "../Services/svBlogPost.asmx/GetAllBlogPost2",
                            method: "get",
                            params: { pn: pageno, ps: pagesize }
                        }).then(function (response) {
                            $scope.ab = response.data;
                        })
                    };
                    $scope.btnSearch = function () {
                        if (vm.ddlBlogKeyword == undefined) {
                            //do nothing
                            getData(pageno, pagesize);
                        }
                        else {
                                $http({
                                    url: "../Services/svBlogPost.asmx/SelectByKeyword2",
                                    method: "get",
                                    params: { k: vm.ddlBlogKeyword }
                                }).then(function (response) {
                                    $scope.ab = response.data;
                                });
                            }
                    }
                    vm.loadNextPosts = function () {
                        pageno += 1;
                        getData(pageno, pagesize);

                    }
                })
```

Comment: Your service should return the count of total records in the data and you should write the logic to display alert if the pageno*pagesize > count of total number of records in the success function of the http call

Comment: This is remodeled code sir.                                             vm.loadNextPosts = function () {
                    if (pageno * pagesize <= $scope.nobp) {
                        pageno += 1;
                        getData(pageno, pagesize);
                    }
                    else {
                        alert('reached the last page');
                        //$("#loadNextPosts").prop('');
                    }
                }

Comment: so is it working?

Comment: Yes sir its working perfectly...You are the best sir thank you and God bless

Comment: Glad to know it was fixed. Appreciate if you can upvote.